# GUI or Visual Studio-plugin for managing Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Are there a GUI or addon for Visual Studio to manage Entity Framework Code First migrations? For example a useful feature would be where you can select a migration from a list and perform an Update-Database with it as a TargetMigration.

(I was thinking of writing such a tool, but am unsure about how to communicate with the Nuget Package Manager Console, where the commands are inserted.)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no such a tool with features that you want, so I beleive there is **no direct answer** to your question. But I found these;

How about:
https://www.red-gate.com/blog/database-lifecycle-management/deploying-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-with-t-sql

Or next generation tool for os-free (command line bassed):
http://www.bricelam.net/2014/09/14/migrations-on-k.html

Interesting one:
https://flywaydb.org/